# rake throws an error: undefined method `reserved=' for #<FriendlyId

Tags: methods, rake, undefined

I run rake and I get this error. What's that supposed to mean? Sorry I'm newbie to RoR sb please help. Thanks a lot.

```
undefined method `reserved=' for #<FriendlyId::ActiveRecordAdapter::Configuration:0x2b1ae5c2ec70>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **reserved_words** instead of **reserved**.

There was a code change in recent versions of friendly_id.

http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Configuration.html#reserved_words-instance_method

Answer (score 0):

may be you are using **reserved=** instead of **reserved** on your FriendlyId object.

Comment: In fact I tried to deploy Eventicus, which is successfully deployed by the author. 
github.com/webmatze/eventicus.de

The problem was due to friendly_id gem: the code runs OK in version 2.2.7 and fails in version 3.0.4; Don't know why it fails while it should not. Anyway, I use friendly_id 2.2.7 now and it works.